# Wordpress / WooCommerce Back-Order Custom Text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have found two bits of code that are really useful for setting "backorder" text on our website, however they need to be combined to work properly:

The first simply changes the text for all backorders

And the second works when a meta_value is present by displaying the custom meta_value text, however displays nothing if no meta_value is present.

Ideally the way i would want it to work, is for it to display the custom text if there is something present, or some pre-defined text if the meta_value is unavailable for that product.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

**FIRST SAMPLE CODE I FOUND:**

```
function backorder_text($available) {

foreach($available as $i) {

$available = str_replace('Available on backorder', 'Will ship in March', $available);

}

return $available;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability', 'backorder_text');
```

**SECOND SAMPLE CODE I FOUND:**

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability' , 'revised_woocommerce_get_availability' , 10, 2 );

function revised_woocommerce_get_availability( $available_array , $product) {

if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {

  if ( !($product->is_in_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() > get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_no_stock_amount' ))  && ($product->backorders_allowed() && $product->backorders_require_notification())  ) {

  $custom_meta_value = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'Out_of_stock_message', true );
 $available_array["availability"] = $custom_meta_value;
   }
}

    return $available_array;
}
```